How do I enter OTP through selenium for my Android App
I want to automate my Messenger app, but I am stuck at the OTP verification screen.
The OTP field is not an editable text. i want to know how I can access that and enter the OTP.
Can anyone assist please. Let me know if you need any more information.
Thank you
I tried using;

xpath and sendkeys


JavascriptExecutor otp  =  (JavascriptExecutor)  driver;
otp.executeScript("document.getElementById('org......securesms:id/container_zero').value = '2';"); 



AndroidDriver dr = (AndroidDriver) driver; dr.pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.NUMPAD_6));




public class OTPVerification {
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
    DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
    caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "your_platform_version");
    caps.setCapability("deviceName", "your_device_name");
    caps.setCapability("appPackage", "com.facebook.orca"); 
    caps.setCapability("appActivity", ".activity.MainTabActivity"); 
    caps.setCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator2");

   
    AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"), dc);

    
    
    MobileElement otp = (MobileElement) driver.findElementById("com.facebook.orca:id/otp_field");

  
    otp.clear();


    String otpCode = "123456";
    otp.sendKeys(otpCode);


    MobileElement verifyButton = (MobileElement) driver.findElementById("com.facebook.orca:id/verify_button");
    verifyButton.click();

    
    Thread.sleep(5000);

    driver.quit();
}

}
Here You can use this approach.
